# DYNAMIC_FEATURES of asterisk in meetme application is not working

Tags: asterisk

i have created meetme application in asterisk and using DYNAMIC_FEATURES of asterisk ,but it is not working.
i am trying to dial *0 during the call for using dynamic feature in meetme. my asterisk is not recognizing anything. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need set variable DYNAMIC_FEATURES

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+features.conf

Also you need sure you dtmf is passed ok(see dtmf debug)